# window.onbeforeunload javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show `div` with some contents when user tries to close the window. I have done the following JavaScript code to do so:

```
function closeWindow(){
                if(submitted == false)
                {
                    $("#confirmation").show();
                    return 0;
                }
            }
window.onbeforeunload = closeWindow();
```

Whenever I close window, alert is appearing for confirmation. I don't want to show that confirmation message instead show `div` with id `confirmation`.

Is there any way to prevent that confirmation alert ?

Comment: No can do. All you can do in `onbeforeunload` is return a string - which the browser *may* display as a confirmation alert (native) to the user.

Comment: No you can't prevent it.

Comment: The `unbeforeunload` popup is built into the browser object and sadly cannot be modified.